# List of dict to Pandas DF - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a list of dict into a pandas DF. One row look like this : `{'id': 5102, 'lat': 41.9258689, 'lng': -91.4231934}`

When I look at the type() I got `int, float, float`

`temp_df = pd.DataFrame(geocode_list)`

Then I got the error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'`

I don't know what cause this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the list does not contain a `None` (so one or more `None`s instead of dictionaries in the list)?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your sample data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you mean `None` instead of a full row or `None` in some values ? Like `{id: 1234, lat: None. lng: 23.234234}`

Comment: @Ragnar: no, like `[{'id': 5102, 'lat': 41.9258689, 'lng': -91.4231934}, None, {'id': 5104, 'lat': 41.9258689, 'lng': -91.4231934}]`.

Answer (score 4):

Generated your possible problem, check out the following fix:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

random = np.random.uniform(size=(100, 2))
data = [{'id': i, 'lon': x[0], 'lat': x[1]} for i, x in enumerate(random)]

# added invalid entry
data[20] = None

# filter out invalid entry
data = [i for i in data if i is not None]

# should work now
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dict does not contain a None .then this will work:-

```
pd.DataFrame(list(geocode_list.items()), columns=['id', 'lat','lang'])
```